# How to delete every row before yesterday of a sharepoint list using pnp powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have this code below that deletes every row before today, but I need to delete every row before yesterday. Is that possible?

```
connect-pnponline -url xxx -Credential $credential
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "xxx" -Query "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Datum'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='Datum'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Lt></Where></Query></View>"
$items.Count
foreach($item in $items) 
  {
   write-host "removing item: " $item.Id
   Remove-PnPListItem -List "xxx" -Identity $item.Id -Force  
  }
```

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.
You could try this caml:

```
       <Lt>
         <FieldRef Name='Created' />
         <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today Offset='-1' />
         </Value>
      </Lt>
```

Updated:

```
<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Datum'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='Datum'/><Value Type='DateTime'>
                <Today Offset='-1' />
             </Value></Lt></Where></Query></View>
```

Comment: Hey thanks but how can i implement your solution into my code

Comment: Check the update.